# Laravel 5 : Validate a field from 2 tables with different message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a table 'user_temps' which contains the new user until they confirmed their subscription. Once done, i copy the user to the 'users' table.

In the registration form i have this validation params :

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user_temps|unique:users',
```

The problem is there I need to have 2 different messages :
if the user is in the 'user_temps' table and another one if the user is in the 'users' table.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you storing unconfirmed users in a separate table? Just have a `confirmed` column which contains a boolean, and a `confirmed_at` timestamp column if you want to know when the user confirmed their account.

Answer (score 1):

you can set custom validation message

```
$rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user_temps|unique:users'
    );
    $messages = array(
        'email.required' => 'Email is required',
        'email.email' => 'Email need to be email type',
        'email.unique:user_temps' => 'This email is already exists in user temps table',            
        'email.unique:users' => 'This email is already exists in users table',           
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: The  'email.unique:user_temps' and 'email.unique:users' are never displayed. Only 'email.unique" is displayed :(

Answer (score 1):

After trying some bad solutions someone (tank you pmall) gave me the answer in another place :

I defined my own validator for the temporary user

```
public function validateTempUserEmail($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return UserTemp::where($attribute, $value)->count() == 0;
}
```

And now the rule for validate the email is

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|TempUserEmail|unique:users',
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things, could you not do the following:

In your user's table, have a boolean column named 'subscribed' defaulted to 0. Then when they've confirmed their subscription you could set it to 1?

Then, upon [authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication), you can run this check:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'subscription' => 1]))
{
    // The user is active, subscribed and exists.
}
```

Comment: Yes Ben I could do as you suggest but I don't find this way 'beautiful' :) I found the solution

Comment: @Lolo It’s a lot more “beautiful” than having two tables for users.

Comment: Martin : May be Im too old for the new school way of programming but personnaly I perfer to have a table for a user before he activated his account and the table to use in all pages. And by doing like this you save a scope (or a where()). You don't have to verify @ each access if the user is valid.